# Is this code not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static method that reads a image using JCGM API .

```
public static BufferedImage readBlackAndWhite(final ImageInputStream pIntputstream,
    Dimension pDim) throws IOException {
    ImageReaderSpi lCgmImageReaderSpi = new CGMImageReaderSpi();
    CGMImageReader lReader = new CGMImageReader(lCgmImageReaderSpi);
    lReader.setBlackAndWhite(true);
    lReader.setInput(pIntputstream);
    return lReader.read(0, pDim.width, pDim.height);
}
```

Which i think is not thread safe .because this method is static and `pIntputstream` and `pDim`  will cause a problem in multi thread environment .

adding synchronized to the method definition will make it thread safe .
but reduce the performance

i want to know what is the other best way of making this method thread safe . keeping performance in mind ?

Comment: for safer side, you can use runnable interface also.

Comment: This question is very general at the moment and this is a really broad topic. There is no best way to go about thread safety.

Comment: Like @radiodef said, it is a general question. Consideration that `Dimension` is mutable, the method itself is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is thread safe if you guarantee the following:

1) Your stream isn't shared with other threads (Streams are rarely thread safe - they expect to be handled by a single thread)

2) Your Dimension object is either: a) immutable b) not shared with any other thread c) Thread safe d) Effectively immutable - meaning that other thread possibly manipulated it, but then published it in a safe manner for other threads to use, and no state modifications took place since then.

3) The constructors of CGMImageReaderSpi and CGMImageReader, as well as the read method of ImageInputStream aren't messing with some state variables which are shared with other threads.

Alternatively, if one or more of the above doesn't hold, the code can still be thread safe if it's always executed in a mutually exclusive way, using some kind of lock (e.g. synchronized block).

Answer (score 0):

If more than 1 threads are calling `readBlackAndWhite` with same `pIntputstream` then it's potentially unsafe. InputStreams are often read in chunks by multiple calls to its `read` method. Imagine many threads interchangeably calling `read` over the same input stream, sounds bad isn't it?

Making it synchronized should make it safe because only one thread can be inside `readBlackAndWhite` at any given instance, but as you mentioned it will reduce throughput.

If you don't want to make it synchronized, other method I can think of is provde each thread with its own copy of the InputStream for reading, so it's completely isolated from the other threads.